# Programs to generate "random" data based on (broken) compression algorithms

Tags: compression

Sometimes it's fun to look the results of deliberately broken decompression - you change compressed file a bit and decompress it. Resulting file is broken from a certain position, derailing data: "slightly modified" -> "looks like normal data at the first glance, but weird" -> "gibberish with recognizable parts of source data" -> "pseudorandom" -> zeroes. Sometimes you get funny piece of text (which is still based around the source data by the form, but essentially random).

Usually I use [paq8l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) if I want to play with it (also funny mode when you edit compression level in the file), but the amount of not-completely-broken part is small: it quickly diverges to noise and then zeroes.

- Are there special programs that read source data and generates "similar" data (with flexible scale of similarity) employing algorithms similar to ones used in compression programs?
- Can ability to generate interesting noise be connected with compression ratio (approx. "quality") of the algorithm?
- Can I tell some existing decompresser "don't stop at the end of compressed data, just think up something based on random data (having state inspired by real data)"?

P.S. I already know about Markov chains, I'm looking for more sophisticated things.

Comment: I'm not certain this question is on-topic. I mean, do you have any real goal?

Comment: What is a real goal? It's interesting what will happen there and what will it be similar to. May be it can be used somehow for "real goals" too, for example, for easy generation of content for fuzz tests.

Comment: The only question left on the now-burninated 'Fun' tag...

Comment: Means "SuperUser community does not like fun". This questions also had a counter near "close" button.

Comment: Looks like the answer can come iif I implement such thing myself.

Comment: @SamB It's a billion dollar industry now. Shows you the importance of basic research.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76681220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented myself, using [lpaq](http://encode.ru/threads/874-lpaq1-is-here) as source.

Link: https://github.com/vi/lpaq1_stream

Answer (score 0):

> Are there special programs that read source data and generates "similar" data (with flexible scale of similarity) employing algorithms similar to ones used in compression programs?

Answer ten years later: Yes, they are called generative artificial intelligence programs. They read the entire internet, and you can choose the scale of similarity. It is debatable whether their algorithms are similar to ones used in compression programs.

The generative A.I. programs are different from lossless compression in that they do not recreate a given text. However, you could say that the prompt given to the A.I. is the compressed version of the inflated text you obtain when it generates its output.

You could do an experiment where you ask for a summary of a text, and then use the summary as a prompt to rewrite the text (maybe giving a length constraint). For some boiler-plate type genre, the quality of the original and the deflated/inflated text might be similar, so this has the character of compression and decompression.